Change IDE background color in Microsoft Visual Studio
I am an Emacs user who has to use MSVS IDE for a project. I am very happy overall except that I am trying to find a way to change the background color of the code editor. I prefer light gray and light brownish shades. I do not want to use the built-in color themes since I don't like them at all. Is there any way that I can do this?
PS. I am looking for a simple RGB setting in a config XML somewhere in VS to set the RGB of the background since this color should be a specific value that I am used to it for a very long time (since 2001)

For Visual Studio IDE (as opposed to VS Code), open the program and go to Tools => Options on the menu, and then the Environment => Fonts and Colors section:

I did find this xml file on my system:

%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_b416740d\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings

You might be able to use this to copy settings between different systems once you get it the way you want, but you'll likely find editing this file more challenging to get things right initially.

That served my purpose. Thank you!

Yes, thank you for finding the XML location of the config! I couldn't find this anywhere on the Web (including their docs and copilot)
